# What happens when Goose, or her species, swallow people?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-marvels

In *The Marvels* movie, Goose and

> her kittens rescued S.H.I.E.L.D. agents from the space station by swallowing them and later vomiting them back out on Earth. In the process, no humans died.

What exactly happens to the humans who are swallowed? Even assuming a stomach that is bigger on the inside, how do they breathe?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's S.A.B.E.R. people rather than S.H.I.E.L.D people.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is stated by [director Nia DaCosta](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarvelStudiosSpoilers/comments/15qcv8l/the_marvels_director_nia_dacosta_talks/), that inside of Goose there is a "pocket universe" and that is where the things go when swallowed. And from there they can come back unharmed.

Here is an excerpt from the linked page:

> Alongside the enormous tentacles concealed inside their deceptively tiny bodies, flerkens house **pocket universes**. They're basically the TARDIS of critters in the MCU. DaCosta reveals we'll see some further use of Goose's **inner pocket universe** in The Marvels